# Two Eventhandler for same Key

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX Scene with with a login form and a register form which slide into the scene from the outside. The main anchorpane is `root` and the other two are `login_form` and `register_form`. Each form has one button - `login` which is calling `login()` and `register` which is callling `register()`.

`login_trigger` and `register_trigger` are two buttons which let the forms slide in. When the login form slides in, I should be able to open `login()` when I press Enter. The same for the register form.

That's what I have thought, but whenever I press Enter, nothing happens. It is working without a problem with the buttons but not with Enter. I would like to have the Eventhandler set to the form which is displayed.

I thought it would work when I set the EventHandler to null, when the form is closing and to give it a value when it's opening. Is there another way to do it or do I have just a stupid mistake in my code?

```
login_trigger.setOnAction(e -> {
    if (login_form.getTranslateX() != 0) {
        openLogin.play();
        login.setOnKeyPressed(e2 -> {
            if (e2.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                login();
            }
            });
        if (register_form.getTranslateX() != 1280) {
            closeRegister.setToX(1280);
            closeRegister.play();
        }
    } else {
        login.setOnKeyPressed(null);
        closeLogin.setToX(-250);
        closeLogin.play();
    }
});

register_trigger.setOnAction(e -> {
    if (register_form.getTranslateX() != 1030) {
        openRegister.play();
        register.setOnKeyPressed(e2 -> {
            if (e2.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                register();
            }
        });
        if (login_form.getTranslateX() != -250) {
            closeLogin.setToX(-250);
            closeLogin.play();
        }
    } else {
        register.setOnKeyPressed(null);
        closeRegister.setToX(1280);
        closeRegister.play();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do by adding a key handler to a button: key events are only processed when the control has the keyboard focus, which is unlikely to happen to a button unless you press it (in which case the action handler would be invoked anyway...). If you press tab until the button has focus, then press enter, does the handler get invoked?

Comment: @James_D yes. It invokes when the button is focused. Added the handler to the root pane instead of the buttons. Now it works. Thank you

Comment: I would image that what you really need is an action event handler on the text field(s).